# Pagination current_page not retaining

Tags: pagination, variable

I have the following code:

```
{paginate}
    {pagination_links}
    <div class="block_pager">
        {previous_page}
        <a href="{pagination_url}" class="prev">Previous</a>
        {/previous_page}
        {next_page}
        <a href="{pagination_url}" class="next">Next</a>
        {/next_page}
        {current_page}
        <div class="pages">
            <ul>           
                {page}
                <li ><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number} -  {current_page}</a></li>
                {/page}

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </div>

    {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}
```

Which returns:

[image]

Why is `{current_page}` losing scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no direct negation for `{current_page}` [[source]](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html#9429)

Use a conditional instead:

```
{if current_page}
  <strong>{pagination_page_number}</strong>
{if:else}
  <a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
{/if}
```

Comment: Originally I had an `if` statement - however it is never triggered. I have used your code above like so: `{page}
                       {if current_page}
                       <li class="active" ><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number} -  {current_page}</a></li>
                       {if:else}
                       <li ><a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number} -  {current_page}</a></li>
                       {/if}
                       {/page}` and nothing happens

Comment: Try copy/pasting the code example from the source I linked to. What happens?

Comment: I did that and then changed it to my html, don't really understand but it worked :)

Comment: Glad you got it working